# Htaccess deny access to vendor but allow scss files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm adding a restriction to the htaccess file for apache v2.4. I want to block all access to the /vendor/ folder and all sub-files/folders, but allow scss files to still load.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/vendor(/.*|$)#">
   <Files ".scss">
       Require all granted
    </Files>
    <Files ".*">
       Require all denied
    </Files>
</If>
```

It seems to block the folders and return a 403 error, but all files still load if I try to access them in the browser.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I thought maybe I could use this directory example as an alternative way, but this causes a 500 error.

```
<Directory "/httpdocs/vendor">
    satisfy any
    deny from all
    allow from 192.168.0.1/27
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use it like this:

```bash
# deny all files in /vendor/
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/vendor/#">
   Require all denied
</If>

# all access to /vendor/*.scss
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/vendor/.+\.scss$#">
   Require all granted
</If>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm wondering if theres a configuration issue on the server. This doesnt work either. I can still load .js files aswell as scss files.

Comment: Did you test from a new browser? I will suggest using command line curl to avoid old cache.